# How to join three tables connected through foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have  set up my models as:

```
class SubItem(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price=models.IntegerField()

class Item(models.Model):
    owner=models.OneToOneField(User)

class ItemSubItems(models.Model):
    item=models.ForeignKey(Item)
    subitem=models.ForeignKey(SubItem)
```

So now I want that for each item I get the sum of "price" of all the subitems which are related to it through  "ItemSubItems" class.

I am trying :

```
item.itemsubitems_set.subitem_set.aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']
```

but I get error 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'subitem_set'.
What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: the subitem_set attribute is available to a specific instance of item (to a specific item object), not to the item class in general.

Comment: @Pynchia So what is the correct approach? for-loop?

Comment: try `Items.objects.annotate(pricesum=Sum('itemsubItems__subitem__price'))`

Answer (score 0):

well, you are almost on the right track.

```
qs = Item.objects.annotate(pricesum=Sum('itemsubitems__subitem__price'))
```

should (I have not tried right now) give you a queryset of all your Items, each of which will have an attribute called `pricesum`, which is the sum of the price of its related subitems.
Please read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards) for more info and examples

P.S:
I have tried it now on models of mine with a similar relationship (see [here](https://github.com/pynchia/gw/blob/master/play/models.py)) 
and the relationship is spanned correctly, without any errors:

```
qs = Subject.objects.annotate(mcount=Count('computer_subject__player__user__username'))
for i in qs:
    print i.name, i.mcount
```

Comment: Gives error "Manager isn't accessible via Item instances"

Comment: there was an extra s in Items, now corrected, but I don't think that is the problem. Please provide more info/context on the error msg and how you use the query

Comment: Just trying to print the query for now